# I cannot load the image in my template, I tried changing all upload file location and everything else and its the same with category field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

```
class product(models.Model):
categoryChoices=[('food','Food'),('clothing','Clothing'),('books','Books'),('furniture','Furniture'),('others','Others')]
product_name=models.CharField(max_length=40)
product_decsription=models.CharField(max_length=100)
pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
image=models.ImageField(upload_to='CharApp/images/',default='')
address=models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
city= models.CharField(max_length=40) 
station= models.CharField(max_length=40)
category= models.CharField(choices=categoryChoices,max_length=30)
```

Views.py

```
def index(request):
donations=product.objects.all()
return render(request,'CharApp/index.html',{'donations':donations})
```

Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('',views.start,name='start'),
path('home/',views.index,name='index'),
path('upload/',views.productFormView),
path('about/',views.about,name='about'),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Forms.py

   class productForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=product
        fields='__all__'

        widgets= {
            'product_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'product_decsription': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'pub_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'image': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'address': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'city': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'station': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
```

template

```
      <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Station</th>
        <th scope="col">Image</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% if donations %}
    <tbody>
    {% for d in donations %}
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>{{d.product_name}}</td>
        <td>{{d.product_description}}</td>
        <td>{{d.category}}</td>
        <td>{{d.station}}</td>
        <td>
            <img src="/{{ BASIC_DIR }}/{{d.image}}" width="120"/>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>no donations</p>
    {% endif %}
```

I tried chnaging the img src call to a d.image.url call,and alot of other things it just doesnt load, the view just doesnt load this field even tho they are available in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your template with

```
{% for d in donations %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">1</th>
    <td>{{d.product_name}}</td>
    <td>{{d.product_description}}</td>
    <td>{{d.get_category_display}}</td>
    <td>{{d.station}}</td>
    <td>
        <img src="{{d.image.url}}" width="120"/>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Explanation:

For each model field that has choices set, Django will add a method to retrieve the human-readable name for the field’s current value. See get_FOO_display() in the database API documentation.

> get_FOO_display

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#choices